# While loop with a certain amount of loops

Tags: unix, while-loop

```
repeat=0
echo "Please enter a number dividable by 5"
read input
loop= `expr  $input / 5`
while [ $repeat -ne $loop ] 
do
echo "repeat"
repeat= `expr $repeat + 1`
done
```

For this code, so if i enter 15, the code will repeat 3 times, it will echo 3 times of repeat, but from now i keep getting command not find from "repeat =`expr $repeat + 1`. not sure what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spacing is important in bash. You need to remove the space after the `=`. i.e.

```
loop=`expr $input / 5`
```

and

```
repeat=`expr $repeat = 1`
```

With that space in place, it is trying to execute the result of the `expr` call, and complaining because there is no command called `3`

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a space after the `=` sign in setting the loop and repeat variable